# Count occurances in a list

Tags: list, haskell, count

I would like to count occurrences of the element in a list in Haskell, but there is an error and I don't know why.

```
count:: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count n []= 0
count n (h:t) | (n `elem` (h:t)) =1+ count (n t) 
       | otherwise = count(n t)
```

Comment: What error? What do you think it means?

Comment: Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Int] -> Int’

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems here: an error that has more to do with the proper syntax, and a *semantical* error.

## Calling a function with "*multiple*" arguments

The error the compiler is probably complaining about has to do with the part in boldface:

```
count:: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count n []= 0
count n (h:t) | (n `elem` (h:t)) = 1+ count (n t)
              | otherwise = count (n t)
```

Something that is quite confusing for most programmers that first programmed in other languages is that one does *not* use brackets for function application. Indeed, in many programming languages if one writes `foo(1)`, then in Haskell you can write `foo 1`.

As a result Haskell interprets the fact that you write `count (n t)` as the fact that the argument of `count` is `(n t)`, and thus that we first performed function application with `n` the function, and `t` the argument. So in Python this would look like `count(n(t))``, which is not what you meant.

Then how do we pass multiple arguments to a function? Well in Haskell every function has exactly *one* argument. If you write `count n` you basically construct a *new* function. By applying the second argument to that new function, we thus "*chained*" function applications, like `count n t`, so we can solve the syntax error with:

```
count:: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count n [] = 0
count n (h:t) | (n `elem` (h:t)) = 1+ count n t
              | otherwise = count n t
```

## Semantical error: `elem` instead of `==`?

But now there is still a semantical error: what will `` n `elem` (h:t) `` do? Indeed it will check if `n` occurs in the **list**. Not per se in the head, so as a result, our function will - in some cases - count a value multiple times. For example `count 3 [1, 2, 3, 4]` will result in `3`. Since `3` occurs `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[2, 3, 4]` and `[3, 4]`. The idea of counting is that we *only* look at the head, and let the recursion look at the remaining elements, so the condition should be replaced with:

```
count:: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count n [] = 0
count n (h:t) | n == h = 1 + count n t
              | otherwise = count n t
```

## Generalizing the type

Now we can make the function more generic: let the function work on lists with different type of objects. In fact there is only one thing that restricts these types: we need to be able to perform [**`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) on it, so we can generalize the type signature to:

```
count:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count n [] = 0
count n (h:t) | n == h = 1 + count n t
              | otherwise = count n t
```

## Counting as a special `foldr` function

Instead of writing this recursion ourselves, we can use `foldr` for this, which is a *catamorphism* on the list. The [**`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) uses a function `f :: a -> b -> b` that takes the head of a list (an `a`), and the result of recursion on the list (a `b`), and thus constructs a new result of type `b`, that then is the result for the entire list. Furthermore the `foldr` function takes a value (of type `b`) that is the value that corresponds to the empty list, it can then perform this operation on a list (`[a]`), and returns the value for that list (a `b`).

Our `count` thus takes a look at the head element, in case it is equal to the element we search, we increment the "accumulator", otherwise we simply pass it, we can thus write count as:

```
count:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count n = foldr (\x -> if n == x then (+1) else id) 0
```

Comment: Another useful way to think about `foldr f z` is that, given a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, which is internally `1 : (2 : (3 : (4 : [])))`, it *replaces* all the `(:)` constructors with a call to `f` and the `[]` constructor with `z`, giving ``1 `f` (2 `f` (3 `f` (4 `f` z)))`` = `f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (f 4 z)))`—in this case, `(if n == 1 …) ((if n == 2 …) ((if n == 3 …) ((if n == 4 …) 0)))`, which for `n = 3` evaluates to `id (id ((+ 1) (id 0)))` = `0 + 1` = `1`.